# Make PHP API methods private

Tags: php, api, security, authentication

I'm working on a user authentication library in PHP. Right now I have both stateful and stateless CSRF protection, everything's secure. My problem is that the API is for remote applications (mobile app, game, etc) and has a public facing script to let a client app perform requests to authorize/log in a user. I would like to include the functionality for creating and removing a user in this API so that the client can do everything itself, but can't figure out a way to make it so that the creation script couldn't just be hit by anybody to flood the database with fake users. When creating a user with the API, I don't require any credentials other than username or password in the request, which means that anyone could hit that script. Does anyone know of a secure solution to this to prevent an attacker from using the API to create/remove users themself?

Answer (score 0):

you could increase obscurity by requiring a secret key. Distribute the key in the client code. However, anyone accessing the client code can see the key and use it. But random people scanning your service wouldn't have the client code, nor the key.

Comment: yeah I thought about that, adding a static "api key" of sorts. as you stated though, it's not secure if it's stored on the client, so I'd rather find a more secure approach